# Is it possible to have polyglot shell documentation encompassing both Fish and POSIX shells in a single script?

Tags: bash, shell, posix, portability, fish

## Context

After a switch to Fish as main shell, one can better feel how this word is full of bash centrism, or at least not very friendly with the friendly interactive shell.

One point that is very common is to find documentation inviting to `echo 'export PATH= "/some/specific/path:$PATH"' >>~/.bashrc`. Or at best it suggest some more generic configuration file like `profile`, `inputrc`, and so on.  While it is rather easy to transpose, it still rise the question: what would be a better more portable alternative to propose as an alternative good practice? That is, is that possible to propose a patch that turns such a Bash/POSIX oriented documentation into a fully functional alternative polyglot shell script which would also works for Fish, and possibly even other shells?

## Challenges

Here is a list of points that make polyglot alternatives difficult to come with when one stay focused on Unix shells (ie. no DOS, no Powershell), or even only taking into consideration Bash and Fish

- assignment: Bash (Korn shell familly actually) use `ilk=nub` where Fish use `set ilk nub` (see [NotTheDr01ds’ answer for more idiomatic way to deal with that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67420197/1307778))
- configuration file: Bash main user configuration file is `~/.bashrc`, while Fish source `~/.config/fish/config.fish`.

## Related resources

- https://superuser.com/questions/446925/re-use-profile-for-fish
- https://github.com/oh-my-fish/plugin-foreign-env
- https://hyperpolyglot.org/unix-shells

Comment: What's your question about all this? Is this even related to programming?

Comment: @NicoHaase Apparently "shell scripts" are on topic -- I've seen some similar questions that felt borderline to me that others felt were firmly on-topic).  My issue is that this seems more an "opinion question" (at least the way it is phrased ... *"what would be a better and more portable ..."*)

Comment: @psychoslave In the "Related Resources", you link to some suggested ways to handle this, but you don't mention why those don't work for you. That also seems to make it like you are asking for "opinions".  The problem with these types of questions on Stack Exchange is that there could be dozens of "right" answers, and yet some of them may or may not work for you just because your preferences are different than others.

Comment: "Portable" in the shell world means targeting the POSIX standard, not picking two shells that don't even try to be compatible with each other and trying to write code that nonetheless would work in either.

Comment: @chepner While I agree that "portability" typically means POSIX, there is also the concept of a [polyglot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_(computing)). The OP can, I believe, be forgiven for not knowing the right term.  I was first introduced to the concept in a similar question about writing a shared `fish`/`zsh` script.  Sadly the person who wrote the answer subsequently deleted it, so I can't link to it for reference. No idea why they deleted it, as it was a brilliant piece of code, IMHO.

Comment: I view polyglots as puzzles, not something I want to use in practice.

Comment: Hello, I now took into account some of these constructive feedback, thanks.

NicoHaase: Does the question title sounds more focus now? I consider having good documentation to be an important part of programming. More universally usable documentation is better when possible.

NotTheDr01ds: I'll take care of "mention why those don't work for you" later, thanks.

Comment: Abandoning compatibility with the mainstream (Bourne-compatible) community should be a deliberate decision; if you were unaware of the consequences when you switched to Fish, the best course of action is probably to switch back. Zsh seems to offer at least a modicum of compatibility with POSIX as an option, whilst incorporating various usability improvements which sometimes break backwards compatibility (... which is why I don't like Zsh either)

Comment: Well, there is a large gap between "accepting to face some specific hindrances" and "abandoning all hope of any form of interoperability". I am totally fine with the former, but this doesn't imply the later to my mind.

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference is to just embrace the "`fish` way."

For instance, you mention docs that add to the PATH via an update to the `.bashrc`.  The "`fish` way" would be to `set -Ua fish_user_paths my_new_path` (or use the recently added `fish_add_path` command) *one time*.

Rather than having to to muck through dozens or hundreds of lines of profile and rc files, you (can) have one known place in `fish` to go to check and change your PATH additions (`set --show fish_user_paths`).

This also has the advantage of propagating the change to all running `fish` shell instances, without having to remember to re-source the config or exit and re-enter the shell like you would have to do in `bash`.  This is incredibly useful when you have more than a few terminal windows open on a long-running system.

Of course, if you need `bash` for something, then you can always drop into a `bash` subshell from within `fish`, and then your simple-to-add-and-edit PATH from `fish` is, of course, available in the subshell.  No reason to worry about cross-maintaining a bunch of PATH modifications in your `.bashrc` in that case.